# Sql query get all subordinates of manager given the manager name

Tags: mysql, sql, key

I have one query , I am not getting coorect answer. Please see to it carefully

Employee data is stored in an Employee table with following columns:

EmployeeId (Varchar)
Name (Varchar)
ManagerId (Varchar)
ManagerId refers to the employee id of the Manager whom the employee reports to.

Assuming that all employee names are unique, write a query to get the names of all **immediate sub-ordinates** given the name of the manage

Comment: Please share your query/workaround

Comment: I was thinking in terms of self join , if required .

Comment: Please give sample data and expected output

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name
FROM   Employee
WHERE  ManagerId = (SELECT manager.EmployeeId
                    FROM   Employee AS manager
                    WHERE  manager.Name = '.....');
```

Or using a self-join:

```
SELECT empl.Name
FROM   Employee mana
JOIN   Employee empl
  ON   mana.EmployeeId = empl.ManagerId
WHERE  mana.Name = '.....';
```

Comment: The self join query will not return the desired output

Comment: @PirateX: could you please explain why? What did I do wrong?

Comment: My bad. Your query is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Content from table EMP

```
+-------+--------+-----------+------+-------------+------+------+--------+
| EMPNO | ENAME  |    JOB    | MGR  |  HIREDATE   | SAL  | COMM | DEPTNO |
+-------+--------+-----------+------+-------------+------+------+--------+
|  7839 | KING   | PRESIDENT |      | 17/Nov/1981 | 5000 |      |     10 |
|  7698 | BLAKE  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 01/May/1981 | 2850 |      |     30 |
|  7782 | CLARK  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 09/Jun/1981 | 2450 |      |     10 |
|  7566 | JONES  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 02/Apr/1981 | 2975 |      |     20 |
|  7788 | SCOTT  | ANALYST   | 7566 | 09/Dec/1982 | 3000 |      |     20 |
|  7902 | FORD   | ANALYST   | 7566 | 03/Dec/1981 | 3000 |      |     20 |
|  7369 | SMITH  | CLERK     | 7902 | 17/Dec/1980 |  800 |      |     20 |
|  7499 | ALLEN  | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 20/Feb/1981 | 1600 |  300 |     30 |
|  7521 | WARD   | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 22/Feb/1981 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
|  7654 | MARTIN | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 28/Sep/1981 | 1250 | 1400 |     30 |
|  7844 | TURNER | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 08/Sep/1981 | 1500 |    0 |     30 |
|  7876 | ADAMS  | CLERK     | 7788 | 12/Jan/1983 | 1100 |      |     20 |
|  7900 | JAMES  | CLERK     | 7698 | 03/Dec/1981 |  950 |      |     30 |
|  7934 | MILLER | CLERK     | 7782 | 23/Jan/1982 | 1300 |      |     10 |
+-------+--------+-----------+------+-------------+------+------+--------+
```

**Query**

```
   SELECT e1.empno EmployeeId, e1.ename EmployeeName, 
           e1.mgr ManagerId, e2.ename AS ManagerName
    FROM   emp e1, emp e2
           where e1.mgr = e2.empno
           and e2.ename='JONES';
```

With Self Join

```
select *
from emp employee
join emp manager
on manager.empno=employee.mgr
where manager.ename='JONES'
```

**Result**

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| EMPLOYEEID | EMPLOYEENAME | MANAGERID | MANAGERNAME |
+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
|       7902 | FORD         |      7566 | JONES       |
|       7788 | SCOTT        |      7566 | JONES       |
+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
```

P.S - I tested on Oracle DB and not MySQL. However the code still works for MySQL